# How to apply highchart's license

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

Few days ago I bought a highchart's license but I am confused how should I use it in my graphs.
Only I need to set credits option like,

```
credits: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Or do I need to specify my license key somewhere else in the code?

Comment: I think that kind of question is better to ask Highcharts sales team directly. I'm pretty sure they have much better knowledge than some programmers on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 9):

You just need to set:

```
credits: {
    enabled: false
}
```

[forum post](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10288)

I did it in the global settings for my app:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    ...
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

I then just created a license folder for highcharts somewhere in my app where I dropped the license PDF my company gave me upon purchase (just for completeness).

Comment: I tried to find some official documentation, but couldn't. Do you have a link to it maybe?